# Codeigniter: /foldername/controllername giving 404 on server

Tags: codeigniter

Uploading an application that works fine on my wamp server but not on the development server.

I have most of my controllers in folders.
For instance "/profile/login" is a controller and calling the url "/profile/login" correctly calls the index function on the controller when i do it in localhost.

But when I upload to my server it returns the default 404 codeigniter page. The index.php still works though.

I removed the .htaccess file since I thought that might have something to do with it but didn't change anything.

Also I tried changing the `$config['uri_protocol']` to the different types.

Whats wierd is that while profile/login doesn't work /login/ does. Even though the login controller is located in the profile folder.

I guess I could create custom routes for all controllers but that seems stupid. I could also rework the controllers so they aren't located in folders.

But I have a feeling this is something incredibly stupid I've missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out just now as I was posting this...
Was overriding an old version of the app and forgot to delete the old files where some of them had the same names and class names as the new controllers.
Ex application/controllers/profile/login.php vs application/controllers/login.php

So... hopefully this will help someone else not wasting their time like I just did :)